# accessing a function inside jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, selector, public

I need a function to be a public so i can call it inside any jquery selector ,
here is the code .
note : console sayes that checkFeat fn is not defined .

```
   (function checkFeat() {
    $(".feat").each(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).children("P").css("display","none")
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).children("P").css("display","block")
        }
    });    
}());

$(".feat h5").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent(".feat").addClass(function(index ,currentClass){
        checkFeat();  //console says this function is not defined why ?!!
        return "active";
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove the wrapping and invoking parens and invoke it like you would any normal function.

Comment: That is correct. Self-invoking functions cannot be invoked from anywhere else in javascript.

Comment: As to the "why", it's because a function *expression* with a name scopes the name to the body of the function itself, so it can only be used within that function.

Comment: thanks dude the problem was in the self invoke (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Javascript file, you can just write:

```
function checkFeat() {
  $(".feat").each(function(){
      if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
          $(this).children("P").css("display","none")
      }
      else
      {
          $(this).children("P").css("display","block")
      }
  });    
}

$(".feat h5").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent(".feat").addClass(function(index ,currentClass){
        checkFeat();  //console says this function is not defined why ?!!
        return "active";
    });
});
```

Then if you want to separately call the function, you can simply call:

```
checkFeat();
```

Answer (score 0):

You restricted the `checkFeat()` inside a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and was unavailable to be used outside the enclosed environment. Remove it and everything should work perfectly.

[MDN JS DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables
>   (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope).
>   In other words, these functions 'remember' the environment in which
>   they were created.

```
function checkFeat() {
    $(".feat").each(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).children("P").css("display","none")
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).children("P").css("display","block")
        }
    });    
}

$(".feat h5").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent(".feat").addClass(function(index ,currentClass){
        checkFeat();
        return "active";
    });
});
```